# Where are the actual .db files stored in wordpress

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I am trying to learn more about wordpress and am bothered with this question.

I hosted my site on bluehost and decided to make a backup. I made a copy of **public_html** and downloaded it, I was later told by the support that I also need to export the database. That got me thinking where the actual data is located, if not in the `public_html` directory, where are the actual files that contains all the tables etc?

I asked the support but didn't get a good answer. Surely, all the data must be stored in some files somewhere, so shouldn't I be able to find them, download them, and not have to use an interface like PhpMyAdmin?

Comment: Who told you about any `.db` files?

Comment: @MichaelZukowski I have experimented with SQLite and Postgres in the past and I then had .db files to store the data, so I assumed MySQL would be using some sort of database files as well.

Comment: SQLite database is not suited for a Wordpress site, because it's not suited for concurrent access in general in terms of writing to it.

Answer (score 1):

On BlueHost ask them to give you an export of SQL File of your database.

If you go the management panel and find MySQL (Database Software) where WordPress database files are stored.

But its best to install plugins like Wordpress DB backup in your WordPress and then use that plugin to download a backup of the database file. That may be easier for you considering you are a non-technical user.